# Logo placement between divs in header

Tags: html, css

I have two parts in my header and I wish to have the logo to be placed between the one on top and the other on the bottom. How can I achieve it using html and bootstrap css?

Here is my header : 
[image]

Here is my code :

```html
    <div class="bg-top navbar-light">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row no-gutters d-flex align-items-center align-items-stretch">

          <div class="col-lg-12 d-block">
            <div class="row d-flex">
              <div class="col-md d-flex topper align-items-center align-items-stretch py-md-4">
                <div class="icon d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center"><span class="icon-paper-plane"></span></div>
                <div class="text d-flex align-items-center">
                  <span>Horaire : 8:00AM - 6:00PM</span>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="col-md d-flex topper align-items-center align-items-stretch py-md-4" style="margin-left: 20px;">
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center"></div>
                <div class="text d-flex align-items-center">
                  <span><a class="navbar-brand ml-5" href="index.php"><span class="mr-1"><img height="54px" width="54px" src="./images/logo.jpg" ></span></a>
                  </span>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="col-md d-flex topper align-items-center align-items-stretch py-md-4">
                <div class="icon d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center"><span class="icon-phone2"></span></div>
                <div class="text d-flex align-items-center">
                  <span>Appelez-Nous: +21260011223</span>
                </div>
              </div>

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark ftco-navbar-light" id="ftco-navbar">
      <div class="container d-flex align-items-center">
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#ftco-nav" aria-controls="ftco-nav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="oi oi-menu"></span> Menu
              </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="ftco-nav">
          <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto text-center ml-5">
            <li class="nav-item active text-center"><a href="index.php" class="nav-link pl-0">Acceuil</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a href="project.php" class="nav-link">Projects</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a href="Services.php" class="nav-link">Services</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a href="about.php" class="nav-link">A propos de nous</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a href="blog.php" class="nav-link">Blog</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a href="contact.php" class="nav-link">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
```

Comment: « Acceuil » is written « Accueil », just saying.

Answer (score 0):

add a

```
style="margin-top:50px"
```

to your img html tag
you will have to change 50px to be whatever the actual number of pixels down you want it.

Comment: it just pushes the div down , doesn't mingle with it

Comment: Try adding position: fixed or position: absolute to the style as well and then see what happens. This may cause the image to end up stuck to the left side of the browser but that can be fixed by adding the left: 50% tag as well